# How to retrieve languages in which a Knowledge Article is translated

Tags: soql, knowledge, translation

I have knowledge articles created in `en_US` in my org and want to query  in what other languages the article has been translated

Comment: Did you try to query the Article Type object for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to fetch what other languages it has been translated to is to filter on the knowledgearticleid or Id in your soql.

As per the SOAP API Developer Guide documentation on [KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm):

> Always filter on a single value of Language. However, in SOQL, you can
>   filter on more than one Language if there is a filter on Id or
>   KnowledgeArticleId.

example SOQL:

```
SELECT Title, language
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='Online' AND
 knowledgearticleid='kA0f40000004Wq7CAE'
```

Comment: Thank you @glls :) It worked and I can pass the list of Ids

Comment: :thumbsup: @C0DEPirate